# JQuery show and hide data from a query in list format that displays parent clickable list that opens its child list

Tags: php, jquery

I am going to try and explain this as clearly as I can.

I am working with some script from @Prabu Parthipan which uses JQuery to open and close child lists of parent lists.

I have a query that returns an array of data. In the array I have two fields:

SeqHeader
SeqText

Each SeqHeader has variable number of SeqText items.

Example:

```
SeqHeader:Bedroom Door & Frame (inside & Outside) 
    SeqText:Chipped - Scratched - Stained - Needs Paint
    SeqText:Chipped - Threshold - Sand/Stain - Repair
    SeqText:Door Hinges - Squeaks/Sticks - Requires Oil/Repair
SeqHeader:Entry Door Lock
    SeqText:Room Door Handle/Strike plate - Not Secure/Not Working
    SeqText:Security Door Chain - Not Working
    SeqText:Room Door Dead Lock - Not operating Correctly
SeqHeader:Bathroom Door Lock
    SeqText:Door Handle/Strike plate - Not secure/Not Working 
    SeqText:Door Lock - Inoperable
```

I could display the above as rows using a PHP do while loop but I though it would be better to produce a list with sublists that open and close.

So adopting Prabu Parthipan code 
@Prabu Parthipan code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('ul li.expanded > a')
.attr('data-active','0')
.click(function(event){
   $('.submuneu').hide();    
    if($(this).attr('data-active')==0){
        $(this).parent().find('ul').slideToggle('slow');
        $(this).attr('data-active','1');
    }
    else
      $(this).attr('data-active','0');        
});
    $('a.on').click(function(){
    $('a.on').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

});
```

In the body of the page I have:

```
<?php do { ?>
        <tr>
         <td colspan="3" class="imaindateselleft_padding">
          <div class="leftsidebar_templ1">
          <ul id="nav">
            <li class="expanded"><a class="on"><?php print $row_AuditItems['SeqHeader']; ?></a>
                <ul class="submuneu">
                <li><a><?php print $row_AuditItems['SeqText']; ?></a>  </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          </div>
          </td>
          <td class="imaindatesel">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
<?php } while ($row_AuditItems =   mysql_fetch_assoc($AuditItems)); ?>
```

As it is when the page is loaded it displays a SeqHeader for each SeqText. They are clickable and when clicked they open up the sub list.

What I want to do is have all the SeqText items relating to thier parent SeqHeader as a sublist so when the SeqHeader is clicked all the related sub items show, and click again so they hide.

Sorry if I have rabbled on.

Any help would be great and I thank you for your time.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it make more since to make a simple to use multi-dimensional array of the items you're getting? As I gather, you're using the *deprecated* `mysql` call to get rows of info from a DB. Each row will have the Header and the Text associated. Thus, if you call inline by each, row, you'll have a header for each row. Try the following instead.

```
<?php
    $res = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($AuditItems)) {
        if ($row['SeqHeader'] && $row['SeqText']) {
            if (!$res[$row['SeqHeader']]) $res[$row['SeqHeader']] = array();
            $res[$row['SeqHeader']][] = $row['SeqText'];
        }
    }
?>
<ul id="nav">
    <?php foreach ($res as $k => $v): ?>
    <li class="expanded">
        <a class="on"><?php echo $k; ?></a>
        <ul class="submuneu">
            <?php foreach ($v as $item): ?>
                <li><a><?php echo $item; ?></a></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I believe you're biggest problem now is in HTML layout. But this should help that. Fix that and then determine if the JS is still a problem, though what you want in JS is relatively easy.

Example of Easy JavaScript for dealing with opening and closing submenus using HTML Markup as:

> UL > LI > A + UL > LI > A

```js
// simply jQuery shorthand for document.ready = function() { ...
$(function() {
 // the following is how to add events so that they work for even "dynamically" created elements. 
 // That is, elements created after code/page load.
 $(document).on('click', 'li a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // ensure it doesn't try to follow a link
  // close all possible siblings and cousins
  $(this).parents('li').each(function(i) { $(this).siblings().find('ul').slideUp(); });
  // slide toggle current possible sub menu
  $(this).next('ul').slideToggle(function() { if (!$(this).is(':visible')) $(this).find('ul').hide(); });
 });
 
 // uncomment the following line to ensure all sublist are closed, 
 // however, i strongly recommend this should be done using css
 // $('ul ul').hide();
 
 // change cursor for li elements having a sub menu
 $('li').each(function(i) {
  if ($(this).children('ul').length) { // test if it has a submenu
   $(this).css({ cursor: 'pointer' });
   // just for this test, i'm going to add a background color to A tags on li's having a submenu
   $(this).children('a').css({ backgroundColor: '#f8f800' })
  }
 });
})
```

```css
/*  this simply hides all submenus outright  */
ul ul { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li><a>test1</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a>bleh</a></li>
   <li><a>bleh Blah</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>blo</a></li>
     <li><a>bli</a>
      <li><a>blu</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a>orange</a></li>
        <li><a>fruit</a></li>
        <li><a>apple</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a>ble</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a>gravy</a></li>
        <li><a>steak</a></li>
        <li><a>bra</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </li>
     <li><a>testCc</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a>test2</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a>testPrev</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>testA</a></li>
     <li><a>testB</a></li>
     <li><a>testC</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>testNext</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>testAa</a></li>
     <li><a>testBb</a>
      <li><a>testPrev2</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a>testA1</a></li>
        <li><a>testB2</a></li>
        <li><a>testC3</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a>testNext4</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a>testAa4</a></li>
        <li><a>testBb5</a></li>
        <li><a>testCc6</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </li>
     <li><a>testCc</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a>test3</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a>blah</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi SpYk3HH, that is dam near perfect. The only issue I have is when the page is loaded all the sublists are open. Have I made a mistake in the jquery section?

Comment: @DCJones OK, going to update answer with a little of my own js (u donnt have to use) and a small piece of css.

Comment: Thats perfect. I used your update which is a lot better than the code I nstarted out with. Many thanks for your time. I will mark this answer as correct.

Comment: @DCJones Just fyi, i just made an update to it you might want. The way it was, it would miss closing one thing, sub-sub menus of current menu. So if you closed a menu, any open menus inside it would still be open. This one small change fixes that. The change is from `$(this).next('ul').slideToggle();` ***to*** `$(this).next('ul').slideToggle(function() { if (!$(this).is(':visible')) $(this).find('ul').hide(); });`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $('ul li.expanded > a')
    .attr('data-active','0')
    .click(function(event){
  $('.submuneu').hide();    
  if($(this).attr('data-active')==0){
      $(this).parent().find('ul').slideToggle('slow');
      $(this).attr('data-active','1');
  }
  else
  {
      $(this).attr('data-active','0');        
  }
 });

 $(document).on('click', 'a.on', function(){
   $('a.on').removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
 });
});
```

Some -code generated- elements need to be "listen" using `$(document).on('event', 'element', function(){...});`. 
Hope it helps.